# CDIR notation for configuring Security Groups firewall

Tags: amazon-ec2

In my [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2) instance I am configuring the firewall to allow access from an IP address `1.2.3.4`. The autocomplete feature is completing the addresses to `1.2.3.4/32`. I'm not sure why, and I don't see any mention of this in the [AWS documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation).

I think that this might make sense if I were configuring an address of the type `1.2.3.0` to allow connections from the entire C block, but I am configuring a specific address. It this some usage of the CIDR notation that I am unfamiliar with? What is the autocomplete trying to suggest with this notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The /32 specifies a single address. A c block's CIDR would be 1.2.3.0/24, which would include 254 usable addresses.

Here's a nice little "cheat sheet" for CIDR stuff: http://www.oav.net/mirrors/cidr.html

Comment: I see, thanks. I did not realise that 32 corresponded with the entire address length. Is it necessary, then?